# How to make bash suppose all commands to be git commands?

Tags: git, bash, alias

Can I make bash to suppose the command always to be a git command?

I mean:

If I wrote `push origin master` then it would execute `git push origin master`?

Note: I would use it in git bash (Windows environment), so I do not need regular commands (ls, cd, etc.) to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try this small git shell, instead:

```
gitsh () {
    while read -r -p "gitsh> " -a GITCOMMAND; do
        git "${GITCOMMAND[@]}"
    done
}
```

After that function is defined, run it once, and it will sit in an infinite loop,
reading a command line and passing it as options to the `git` command.

EDIT: Adding the `-e` option to the `read` command, as suggested by gniourf_gniourf, gives you a nice Readline-based environment where you can retrieve and edit your history.

Comment: This is obviously a very good answer. It would be perfect with the `-e` option to `read`.

Comment: Very true. I don't use `-e` often myself, so I didn't consider it.

Answer (score 2):

You could add aliases for commonly used commands e.g. `push` would become `git push` etc. This solution needs to specify all commands you are using, but should not break anything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "git bash" is like regular bash, use the `command_not_found_handle` function:

```
function command_not_found_handle {
  command git "$0" "$@"
}
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Search-and-Execution

The possibility for sending git inadvertent commands exists, but that's what you're asking for in the question.

Comment: I was thinking of this method, but it has flaws with commands that already exist in `$PATH` and that exist in git, e.g., `rm`...

Answer (score 0):

You may add scripts named push, commit etc. to your PATH. This way your shell would have push, commit etc. "commands". This should work with whatever shell you are using, not only bash.